Help me to understand why the interior of this set is empty. [SOLVED]
I need help and confirmation to understand why int$(K)$ is said to be empty, according to my notes, where $K$ is the part of a cone of equation
$$K = \{ (x, y, z) \in\mathbb{R}^3: (3+z)^2 + y^2 = x^2, 0 \leq x \leq 2 \}$$
So, impulsively: the internal part of a set is the set of all the internal points of that set. But as far as I can see, $K$ is compact and connected too. All the points inside of the cone should be internal point. It's like if I had a sphere.
But then, by thinking: the portion of a cone I have is only the "shell" of the cone, like if I had a shell of a sphere. Then considering only the shell, I have no internal points.
Is this correct? Because if this isn't, then I really don't understand why internal of $K$ is the empty set.
Thank you!

Your reasoning is correct. The set is only the "shell" and the volume delimited by it doesn't belong to the set.

@amrsa Aw, thank you so much! I am finally entering in the view then. It's rather relieving. Thank you!!

No point on a boundary is an interior point since every open ball centered at a boundary point contains an element of the complement. The set is all boundary, so it has no interior points.
